# HTML height attribute - limitations on element types which can have their height set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I've been trying in vain to set the height on a container. I've been mainly using this:

```
$rdc.height(rdc_height);
```

I have also tried these:

```
$rdc.height(300);
$rdc.css({height:300});
document.getElementById("RDC162").style.height = rdc_height + "px";
```

These work fine, however (so the problem isn't with the `$rdc`):

```
$rdc.css({padding:20, maxHeight:80});
$rdc.hide();
```

Why can I not set the height on the element? It is `position: relative` if that makes any difference, although when I tested it didn't seem to.

Comment: Have you tried to simply use CSS for that? `height:300px;` I see no reason to use js...

Comment: I can't use CSS; it's a long story :)

Comment: Retagged to add `jQuery`, btw OP if the current answers aren't of help, try reproducing the problem in a live scenario - the part of code you posted is absolutely right.

Comment: Is the outer container `position:relative` i seem to remember that helped in some browsers where i came across this problem before.

Comment: @Qpirate - The outer container is `relative`, but nice idea.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  A good suggestion. I've cut and pasted a huge section from the generated source and it works in isolation :(  Something is clearly interfering - it's in a `sortable` container, for a start. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the element is not a block element.

Try this

```
$rdc.css({display:"block", height:"300px"});
```

Comment: `inline-block` should work too, depending on OP's preference.

Comment: I got excited there for a moment, but alas, it is already a block element and the code didn't have the desired effect.

Comment: Check if CSS !important is used anywhere. Also try this $rdc.css({display:"block", height:"300px!important"});

Comment: Try this $rdc.css({"background-color":"#FF3333", "height":"300px"}); Just want to know if height change is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you really want to use javascript, I don't see why you use $ though.

What you should do is

```
var rdc_height;/* properly make a new variable */
document.getElementById("RDC162").style.height = rdc_height + "px"; /*which you already had*/
```

You were fairly close, but this is a proper way to code it. :)

Comment: I had declared the variable already; I just didn't include it in the demo. Besides, even if I didn't, I would have just inadvertently created a global (evil!) and it would have made no difference :)  I use $varName as a way of reminding myself that this is the jQuery object (because I might have $rdc as the object and rdc as the string of the DOM id).

Comment: If I knew earlier that this was a jQuery question... Don't be shabby with the tags! :)